# iOS core data sync between devices

Tags: core-data, ios7, synchronization

I wrote an app which uses core data to store same private data. and now, I want to make it sync between devices with the same icloud ID. Can anyone show me a easy how to do that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are many tutorials on this, you need to google some more and come back with specific questions after you have tried. Raywenderlich is a great place to start.

Comment: Hi Doug, I did quit a lot of searching but I just can't find a good way to start with. and lot of articles are few years ago. lot of people said core data with icloud is nightmare. that is why I hope to have some suggestion here.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1 just because it was new for iOS 5 doesn't mean it won't show you how to do things. You may need to tweak things a bit but this should get you started. Then if something isn't working and you can't find an answer you can make a new question that is more specific.